# An Instance of SQL query with ORA-00936: missing expression error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm now currently studying in SQL and Oracle Database. I have an short example about what I'm trying to write in a query. Suppose I want to create a table which contains in descending sorted order all the employee’s first names for employees who are either engineers or managers. Keep both
(or more) records if two (or more) employees have the same first name. This is What I have now, but no idea why it shows an ORA-00936: missing expression error when executing it, Can any one help me check this out ?

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT FNAME
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Engineer) OR (SELECT ID FROM Manager)
    ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
```

Here are the definitions of table Employee, Engineer and Manager:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SSN CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FNAME CHAR(15),
    LNAME CHAR(15),
    DOB DATE NOT NULL
);

    CREATE TABLE Manager(
    ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    HATERID CHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT LMAN CHECK (HATERID != ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Employee(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(HATERID) REFERENCES Manager(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Eng_tech(
    ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Employee(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Engineer(
    ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Eng_tech(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Do you want to create a table (which is stored permanently in your database) or do you mean a query (which shows you the results, but does not store them). If you mean a query, leave out the "CREATE TABLE Example AS".

Comment: yes, I wanna create a table which stores and shows the results. Not only a select query.

Comment: You shouldn’t rely too much on that `order by` - Oracle will store it how it wants. As this is a new table, the rows will get stored in the order you specified as kind of a side effect, but if you were to delete some rows here and there and add some more with another `order by` there’s no guarantee what order you’ll see it in when you query it. Also, `varchar2` is the standard string type - `char` is rarely a good choice due to blank padding behaviour that I doubt you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is query :

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT emp.FNAME
    FROM Employee Emp
    JOIN Engineer Eng
    ON Emp.ID=ENG.ID
    JOIN Manager Mgr
    ON Emp.ID=Mgr.ID
    ORDER BY emp.FNAME DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you think your code would be interpreted as this (note the extra parentheses):

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT FNAME
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.ID IN ((SELECT ID FROM Engineer) OR (SELECT ID FROM Manager))
    ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
```

However it was actually interpreted as this:

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT FNAME
    FROM Employee
    WHERE (Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Engineer)) OR (SELECT ID FROM Manager)
    ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
```

`OR` is used to join together two conditions (boolean expressions).  `Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Engineer)` is a boolean expression (it has a true/false value), but `(SELECT ID FROM Manager)` isn't.  Oracle got a bit confused by your code because it was expecting this expression to be compared to something else but didn't find the something else it was looking for.

You probably want the following instead:

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT FNAME
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Engineer)
       OR Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Manager)
    ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
```

You could also write the following, which is in some way closer to what you were trying:

```
CREATE TABLE Example AS
    SELECT FNAME
    FROM Employee
    WHERE Employee.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Engineer UNION SELECT ID FROM Manager)
    ORDER BY FNAME DESC;
```